# Update values on a second spreadsheet and automatically link and update values in the first spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I have two spreadsheets: `Spreadsheet 1`, the initial data is entered manually.  I do an IMPORTRANGE into `Spreadsheet 2` with `order by Col2`. This is what I get when I perform IMPORTRANGE (sort on ID):

```
Name - ID    - Type         
Beer - Beer1 - Light
Beer - Beer4 - Reg
```

`Spreadsheet 2`:  Ready to add more info.

```
Name - ID    - Type   -- size         
Beer - Beer1 - Light  -- 30 pk
Beer - Beer4 - Reg    -- 24pk
```

So far so good.  Now I go back to `Spreadsheet 1` and add:

```
Beer - Beer2 - Dark
```

When I go back to `Spreadsheet 2`  I get the following:

```
Name - ID    - Type   -- size         
Beer - Beer1 - Light  -- 30 pk
Beer - Beer2 - Dark   -- 24pk
Beer - Beer4 -
```

How do I fix this issue so it shows the following in `Spreadsheet 2`:

```
Name - ID    - Type   -- size         
Beer - Beer1 - Light  -- 30 pk
Beer - Beer2 - Dark   --  "I would have to enter this data"
Beer - Beer4 - Reg    -- 24pk
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing your Spreadsheet, or an example of it?

Comment: I have found that docs have trouble using manual information from two locations. Why can't you include this information in SS 1?  Alternatively, have you might try a lookup list if the "Size" comes from a pre-defined list.

Answer (score 0):

You are placing two ranges of data next to one another and expecting one range to be aware of the other. This is not possible without giving the spreadsheet indication of what constitutes a match.

The conventional solution is to have a lookup table in which each pair (same row) of your left-hand columns is positioned to correspond with the values presently a pair (same row) of your right-hand columns. Then use something like [HLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093375), [VLOOKUP](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318) or an [INDEX](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098242) and [MATCH](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093378) in combination to populate the two right hand columns from that.